# Process a large amount of data in Spring @Service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I faced a requirement to process a large amount of data for every request and I'm looking for some clues. I came up with three ideas:

- 1) start a new thread from a service
- 2) use request scope for a service
- 3) use @Async

I realized I don't fully understand the basics:

- If all Spring beans are Singletons, what happens in there is a
  time-consuming operation in @Service? Will other users have to wait for @Service to complete?
- If expected service behavior to call DB, fetch and process results
  and do other no trivial operations, shouldn't it be scoped request by
  default?

  What @Async has to do with all this? Is it equivalent to AJAX call?

I would really appreciate some explanation on how to perform heavy calculations for every request in Spring Boot.

Comment: A singleton doesn't mean that while one thread is executing a method other threads would block and wait. Unless it were `synchronized` of course. You need to do a lot of research on the basics before you even think about starting writing code.

Comment: Singleton beans can be used concurrently as long as they are stateless.  Here's the [getting started example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/) to help determine if @Asynch would be a good solution for your particular problem.

Comment: So is it ok to run say 10 min calculation in a service method?

Comment: You need to discuss the specifics with somebody playing the solution architect role.  As a starting point: How many concurrent requests?  Is it okay if all resources in the stack are blocked while waiting? If required, how will you provide progress feedback to the user?

Comment: This a kind of a 'start and forget' action. A user doesn't need to monitor the progress or get updates. He doesn't even need to be notified about the results, as the result will be visible in another app. There can be up to 1000 users, every user can start multiple calculations on different 100-10000 record lists.

Comment: Initially, I have begun with a new job-Thread for every request, created and started from a Service, but since every request creates a thread anyways, this looks like not the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

No, singleton bean doesn't mean other threads have to wait for a thread to finish executing some service offered by that bean.

I see that you mentioned about up to 1000 users requesting concurrent calculation. In that case, `@Async` may not be a good choice.

You can start with a simple ThreadPoolExecutor with some decent value for maximum amount of concurrent thread (16), and work queue size (10000). Since you claim that this is kind of 'start and forget' action, I assume it's OK to have an amount of calculation requests waiting in the work queue until some idle thread available.

Next, do some load test with the starting solution to estimate again the capability of your service. In case your single service doesn't have enough capability to handle such huge amount of heavy calculation requests in time, you would need to think about having dedicated worker service instances where actual calculations are done, while your server service only play as "request dispatcher".

This is not an actual answer but since I don't have enough point to add answer, consider this as some starting point for your problem.